# IPC problem in the c# - ipc is already registered

Tags: c#, ipc, channel

I am trying to create two IPC channels

```
IpcChannel ipcChannel = new IpcChannel("DroolsClient");
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(ipcChannel, false);

objec = (DroolsInterface.RulesEngineInterface)Activator.GetObject(typeof(DroolsInterface.RulesEngineInterface), "ipc://Drools/SreeniRemoteObj");

IpcChannel ipcChannel2 = new IpcChannel("ProxemClient");
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(ipcChannel2, true);

objec2 = (ProxemProject.ProxemInterface)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ProxemProject.ProxemInterface), "ipc://ProxemProcess/SreeniRemoteObj");
```

But when it gets to the second ChannelServices it gives an error

> The channel 'ipc' is already registered

Would anyone be kind enough to help please

Comment: Have you got a solution there please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question [Two-way communication using IPC](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/d91e38ce-8e38-4a5b-9ecb-6df62006bcf2)

[The channel 'tcp' is already registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839577/the-channel-tcp-is-already-registered)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.